# Google translate breaks my AJAX loaded (relative URL) content

Tags: ajax, relative-path, google-translate

Seems like this must be a common problem, but I cannot find a solution here or on the wider web. Our site loads content via AJAX calls to the server with relative URLs (e.g. using jQuery):

```
$("#mydiv").load("sku123.html", 
  function(response, status, jqXHR) {
    if (status=="error") {
      // Failed
    }
  }
);
```

Works fine until a user requests a google translation of our page, then the AJAX call returns

```
Failed to contact server, connection failed.
```

I notice that `window.location.href` shows the google translate server, not our own. So I guess this AJAX call is going to google which of course knows nothing about the HTML we are trying to fetch (although I would expect a 404, not 'connection failed').

This must be a common problem but what is a good solution? I don't want to hard-code our server into these URLs (then it will break on our development/test systems).

Answer (score 0):

Browser console shows the problem - cross domain requests are failing. Reconfigured the server to allow CORS from https://translate.googleusercontent.com and it all works as expected (with relative URLs). Web.xml for tomcat:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
    <param-value>https://translate.googleusercontent.com</param-value>
  </init-param>  
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Hummm... but the AJAX content is not translated. Ugh.